# Cannot add/remove attribute onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript and jQuery. I am trying to add an attribute on click and remove it on click. I have add and remove class working well but not attribute. My code is below.

HTML below

```
<label class="label_check" for="fadv">
    <input class="lesson" id="fadv" value="acl323" name="fadv" checked="checked" type="checkbox" />Please send me regular updates.
</label>
```

jQuery below

```
<script>
function setupLabel() {
    if ($('.label_check input').length) {
        $('.label_check').each(function(){ 
            $(this).removeClass('c_on');
            $(this).removeAttr('pull');
        });
        $('.label_check input:checked').each(function(){ 
            $(this).parent('label').addClass('c_on');
            $(this).attr('pull' , 'on');
        });                
    };
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').addClass('has-js');
    $('.label_check, .label_radio').click(function(){
        setupLabel();
    });
    setupLabel();
});
</script>
```

Comment: why do you want to add an `attribute` ?

Comment: Could you explain what you want to happen on clicking the checkbox? Or is it the label that should be the click-target?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you empty the attribute value?

```
function setupLabel() {
    if ($('.label_check input').length) {
        $('.label_check').each(function(){ 
            $(this).removeClass('c_on');
            $(this).attr('pull','');
        });
        $('.label_check input:checked').each(function(){ 
            $(this).parent('label').addClass('c_on');
            $(this).attr('pull' , 'on');
        });                
    };
};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').addClass('has-js');
    $('.label_check, .label_radio').click(setupLabel);
    setupLabel();
});
```

Comment: `function(){ setupLabel(); }` could be simplified as `setupLabel`

Answer (score 0):

because label_check doesnt have this attribute :)) could u try this code ?

http://jsfiddle.net/Nzw2K/